# MYSQL Group Gy ordering with Count?

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1140

I'm trying to do something similar to [Select the 3 most recent records where the values of one column are distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924494/mysql-group-by-ordering), but with a count, which means I need to preserve the group.

Using the same example:

```
 id       time      text      otheridentifier
-------------------------------------------
1        6         apple     4
2        7         orange    4
3        8         banana    3
4        9         pear      3
5        10        grape     2

SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM `table` GROUP BY (`otheridentifier`) ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 3
```

would return id of 5, 3, 1 with the proper counts, but I want 5, 4, 2.

The solution in that post was

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'id' = (SELECT 'id'
FROM 'table' as 'alt'
WHERE 'alt'.'otheridentifier' = 'table'.'otheridentifier'
ORDER BY 'time' DESC
LIMIT 1) ORDER BY 'time' DESC LIMIT 3
```

but I don't see how to grab a count, since I need a grouping there: I get `ERROR 1140 (42000): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause` if I add COUNT(*) to the beginning of that.

Comment: You do not have any group by in your sql. What are you trying to count?

Comment: I do in the first query: I'm trying to count the number of items grouped by 'otheridentifier'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY (`otheridentifier`)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

simply change the order-by clause. ordering is done after the grouping/aggregating is completed, so you can sort by the results of those aggregate functions.

Comment: that doesn't seem to preserve my need to order by 'time'.

Comment: So you want the LAST record in any of the groups?

Comment: yes, that's what i want! i'd want the record matching the last time, grouped by otheridentifier, with a count of all in that particular group.

Comment: assuming the ids are an auto-increment column, then simplly select `MAX(id)` instead of `*`, which'd give you the highest ID within each group.

Comment: no, sorry, in my case id is actually a reference from another table. even with this hypothetical example, it works with this configuration, but wouldn't work if 'time' were more random than how it's presented.