# Rails 3: .group() ordered by created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, group-by, sql-order-by

What is the Rails 3 way to order .group() results in Activerecord (here by "created_at")?

```
@messages = Message.group(:foo)
```

only results in displaying the oldest message. I'd need the latest to be shown.

I tried

```
@messages = Message.group(:foo).having("created_at = MAX(created_at)")
```

with no success. Any hints appreciated!

To clarify: I'm looking to have the group ordered within itself, not a normal messages.order("...").
Should there be no easy Activerecord syntax, i'd be happy with raw SQL as well

---

Update: trying the SQL way, this was supposed to work:

```
@messages = Message.find_by_sql("
  SELECT messages.* 
  FROM messages 
  GROUP BY messages.foo 
  HAVING messages.created_at = MAX(messages.created_at) 
  ORDER BY messages.created_at DESC")
```

But this retrieves solely single records (those that are not grouped). Supposedly grouped ones are being omitted. Do not know why, all records have :created_at and :foo values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it all working by using a more dedicated subquery, without a GROUP BY call:

```
SELECT *
   FROM `messages`
   WHERE `id` = (
      SELECT `id`
      FROM `messages` as `alt`
      WHERE `alt`.`foo` = `messages`.`foo`
      ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
      LIMIT 1
   )
   ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
```

All thanks to Chaos' answer in this thread: [Select the 3 most recent records where the values of one column are distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924494/mysql-group-by-ordering/924501#924501)

Don't know about any speed implications yet though. If anyone wants to step in, please feel free to do so.

Comment: I recommend you now consider converting this into 'rails' queries with :conditions, etc.  This is part of using rails "as intended" and getting the hang of it with a fairly simple example like this would be a great exercise.  Writing find_by_sql (which I did for quite a while as my background is sql databases) is part of not using the rails structures and tends to lead to quick results but they are hardcoded and often vendor specific (which also means developer specific..) and less maintainable.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I agree with you. Would you have an example for this query at hand?

Answer (score 7):

You can't use order then group in the same query under some databases, so you need to do it using two queries:

```
message_ids = Message.select("MAX(id) AS id").group(:foo).collect(&:id)
@messages = Message.order("created_at DESC").where(:id => message_ids)
```

*Note: this assumes that you have an auto-incremented `id` column, which most Rails tables do.*

Answer (score 2):

You can go SQL, but you can also mostly stay in activerecord land with

```
@messages = Message.select('DISTINCT ON (foo) *').order(:created_at).reverse_order
```

The `DISTINCT ON ()` syntax is postgres. There's a similar but slightly different syntax in MYSQL.

I think this query will end up being a lot more efficient, too, than the accepted answer because it's just a single sort and scan, instead of N sorts.

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried to get a ordered and unique result list and had to change order on Postgresql: Deadline.select('DISTINCT ON (client_id) *').order(:client_id, :reminder_date)

Answer (score 1):

I have just come across this same problem. The following Rails query worked for me:

```
Message.where("id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages GROUP BY id) AND state = 'unread'")
```

Here we use a sub-query to get the largest (and therefore most recent) ID in each group, and then filter those to only show ones where state == 'unread'.

Tip: I made a self.latest method in my Message model class that consisted of:

```
def self.latest
  where("id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages GROUP BY id)
end
```

Which meant I could use it in controllers like this:

```
Message.latest.where(state: 'unread')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this would be done using Arel easily - but if you just go with constructing your own SQL like you did in your question, then amend it as follows:

```
@messages = Message.find_by_sql("
  SELECT messages.* 
  FROM messages 
  GROUP BY messages.foo 
  HAVING messages.created_at = (SELECT max(created_at) FROM messages AS sub_messages WHERE sub_messages.foo = messages.foo)
```

Note the subquery in the HAVING clause. Your HAVING clause calculated the MAX across all your messages - as opposed to only the messages within foo. The subquery should solve that problem.

I aliased the messages table name to sub_messages - but that shouldn't be necessary. I just did it to 'show' how the parent and subquery work together.

Comment: Thank you Joerg. Tried your suggestion but the query does not return any records for me. I think it looks very resonable a query though! So I would like to figure out why this is the case?

Comment: Just tested this with one single message, which is shown correctly. But as soon as there are more than one (so a GROUP is in effect?), neither is found. Any ideas?