# Order Group By in Activity Stream by Date MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, android-activity, group-by, sql-order-by

I tried a lot of solutions from here, but none of those solved my issue! I have the following table structure:

```
|Column|Type|
|------
|activity_id| int(10) PRIMARY
|user_id| int(10)
|type| varchar(255)
|activity| varchar(255)
|item_id| int(11)
|secundary_id| int(11)
|date| datetime
```

I'm building an Activity Stream, in this table i'll record like

"John (user_id) commented (activity) a post (type => item_id) 5 hours ago (date)"

I intend to do the following structure:

"John,Marie, and +2 commented a post 5 hours ago"

So far i was able to do this connection, but i can't successfully order the records by date. I tried some inner joins in the own table, but with that i was unable to retrieve the other activity types that wasn't grouped by (type,activity,item_id), for example:

"John ( user_id) posted (activity) a post(type => item_id ) 5 hours ago (date)"

When i use JOINS i only get the grouped by records. This is my actual query:

```
SELECT t.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id ) AS users FROM (
SELECT *
FROM activity
   ORDER BY date DESC 
)t
GROUP BY type, activity, item_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

I already tried some solutions listed here: [Select the 3 most recent records where the values of one column are distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924494/mysql-group-by-ordering) 
But when i join the tables, i lost the non grouped records!
Does anyone have another thoughts? Thanks by now!

/** EDIT - RESULTS

```
activity_id     user_id     type    activity    item_id     secundary_id    date    users
865         32  update  comment     20  22  2013-10-29 15:03:49     32,34
858         36  update  post    20  NULL    2013-10-29 13:50:59     36
864         32  post    comment     2615    21  2013-10-29 14:55:58     32,34,36
856         36  post    comment     2616    14  2013-10-29 13:50:10     36,39,34,32
872         32  post    comment     2617    28  2013-10-29 15:46:20     32
852         34  post    post    2615    NULL    2013-10-29 13:47:25     34
854         32  post    post    2616    NULL    2013-10-29 13:49:13     32
870         32  post    post    2617    NULL    2013-10-29 15:36:57     32
```

That's what i get with the query above, but for example the item_id 2616 that have 4 user comments, are not ordering by the last user comment date, for example i have the following record:

```
activity_id user_id type activity item_id secundary_item date
856     36  post    comentar    2616    14  2013-10-29 14:05:10
```

His date is 14:05, but on my select i get another older comment date!

-- FIDDLE

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1923d2/1

---

SOLVED by @Tom

Comment: It's a little hard to understand.  Can you post some sample data, the results you are getting and the results you would like to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the most recent date, try this:

**ORIGINAL**

```
SELECT   activity_id, user_id, type, activity, item_id, secundary_id, MAX(date) date, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id ) AS users 
FROM     activity
GROUP BY type, activity, item_id
ORDER BY date DESC
```

**EDITED** - Below will give you the most recent record for each grouping.

```
SELECT   activity_id, user_id, type, activity, item_id, secundary_id, date, 
         users

FROM     activity a

         JOIN ( SELECT   MAX(activity_id) max_activity_id,
                         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id ) AS users
                FROM     activity
                GROUP BY type, activity, item_id
              ) AS grp ON a.activity_id = grp.max_activity_id

GROUP BY date DESC
```

Comment: I'll try! I build this Fiddle with my structure:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1923d2/1

Comment: That listed right the activity records, but i still geting some older comment (secundary_id) when i display! I mean the order of the activity is write, but not the comments, etc!

Comment: Ok, so for each group you would like to show the values from the most recent record?

Comment: Would the record in each group with the MAX(activity_id) always be the most recent record?

Comment: Yes, i tried with the activity_id but i can't work around, but that's it! The activity_id will always be the most recent!

Comment: @wiLLiamcastrO, how do you use the users column (last one) with GROUP_CONCAT values?

Comment: It's just a comma separated list.  It's informational.