# How to find last 5 records from record sorted in descending order?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Student.StudentID,
        Student.FirstName,
        Student.LastName,
        Student.EmailID,
        COUNT(SUBJECTS.SubjectID) as count from StudentMarks 
INNER JOIN Student 
        ON StudentMarks.StudentID=Student.StudentID 
INNER JOIN Subjects 
        ON StudentMarks.StudentID=Subjects.StudentID 
GROUP BY StudentMarks.StudentID 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT (),();
```

I am calculating the count of total tuples by below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 
        Student.StudentID,
        Student.FirstName,
        Student.LastName,
        Student.EmailID,
        COUNT(SUBJECTS.SubjectID) as count from StudentMarks 
INNER JOIN Student 
        ON StudentMarks.StudentID=Student.StudentID 
INNER JOIN Subjects 
        ON StudentMarks.StudentID=Subjects.StudentID 
GROUP BY StudentMarks.StudentID 
ORDER BY count DESC) 
      as temp;
```

However, I need to integrate this query in my first one, and get the last 5 records. Is there a way to do this? Temp gives me a total of 121 records, and if I can subtract 5 from this and use limit function, it could solve my problem. But I have no clue how to integrate the query over here? Please help!!

Comment: is it required to sort in DESC ?

Comment: Change sort from DESC to ASC (or from ASC to DESC) and use LIMIT 5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Group By ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924494/mysql-group-by-ordering)

Comment: @StanislavL - I want to show the least 5 records in descending order actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not required to SORT in DESC than you can use below approach:

```
SELECT Student.StudentID,Student.FirstName,Student.LastName,Student.EmailID,
 COUNT(SUBJECTS.SubjectID) as count from StudentMarks INNER JOIN Student ON 
StudentMarks.StudentID=Student.StudentID INNER JOIN Subjects ON 
StudentMarks.StudentID=Subjects.StudentID GROUP BY StudentMarks.StudentID ORDER BY count ASC 
LIMIT 5
```

**EDIT FOR SPECIFIC REQUIREMENT**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
     SELECT Student.StudentID,Student.FirstName,Student.LastName,Student.EmailID,
     COUNT(SUBJECTS.SubjectID) as count from StudentMarks INNER JOIN Student ON 
    StudentMarks.StudentID=Student.StudentID INNER JOIN Subjects ON 
    StudentMarks.StudentID=Subjects.StudentID GROUP BY StudentMarks.StudentID ORDER BY count ASC 
    LIMIT 5
)main ORDER BY main.count DESC
```

Comment: I doesnt matter to sort actually. I want the last 5 records only.

Comment: Than you can change ORDER BY count DESC to ORDER BY count ASC and then LIMIT 5.  Check above solution

Comment: @llesh Patel - My requirement is to show last 5 records only.

Comment: have you check above solution?. this will give 5 records only

Comment: Lets say I order by ASC and limit it to 5. Even in that case I need to show the list in descending order.

Comment: @llesh - Awesome dude. Could you please tell me what main.count is doing? Did you create view over here?

Comment: No. first Internal Query takes data in SEC order and limit it to 5. Than Give it alias main. Now outer query takes this main and order by main table with COUNT column. so main.count ASC.

Comment: Great!! Got the logic :-)

Comment: Nice, When you get correct ans than Accept as correct so other view it on the top.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select a.*,temp.C from (SELECT Student.StudentID,
        Student.FirstName,
        Student.LastName,
        Student.EmailID,
        COUNT(SUBJECTS.SubjectID) as count from StudentMarks 
INNER JOIN Student 
        ON StudentMarks.StudentID=Student.StudentID 
INNER JOIN Subjects 
        ON StudentMarks.StudentID=Subjects.StudentID 
GROUP BY StudentMarks.StudentID 
ORDER BY count DESC limit 5)a left join (SELECT StudentID,COUNT(*) as C FROM (SELECT 
        Student.StudentID,
        Student.FirstName,
        Student.LastName,
        Student.EmailID,
        COUNT(SUBJECTS.SubjectID) as count from StudentMarks 
INNER JOIN Student 
        ON StudentMarks.StudentID=Student.StudentID 
INNER JOIN Subjects 
        ON StudentMarks.StudentID=Subjects.StudentID 
GROUP BY StudentMarks.StudentID 
ORDER BY count DESC)temp on a.StudentID =temp.StudentID
```