# how to retrive last group of data using cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

My Two Table Image is given below,

[image]

I have a relation in TblB.php Model

```
public $belongsTo = array('TblA');
```

I use MySQL databse;

```
$results = $this->TblB->find('all', array('group' => array('TblB.tbl_a_id')));
```

Actually, I need last group of data in the **table (tbl_b)**.
How to solve the query using CakePHP.

Comment: Hi, You need last row of the table right ?

Comment: No, I need last group data (After joining the two table)

Comment: What do you mean the _last group_? How do you determine the _last group_ programmatically? Is there another column in tbl_b? Do you just want to pick the largest _Value_ per TableAId?

Answer (score 0):

You want to run the following SQL query to grab the data you want:-

```
SELECT TblB.* FROM tbl_b AS TblB WHERE TblB.id = (
    SELECT TblB2.id FROM tbl_b AS TblB2 
    WHERE TblB2.tbl_a_id = TblB.tbl_a_id 
    ORDER BY TblB2.id DESC 
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY TblB.id ASC
```

See the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1367c/1/0) for this in action.

To do this in CakePHP you will need to build the sub-query using Cake's `buildStatement`:-

```
$db = $this->TblB->getDataSource();
$subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
    array(
        'fields' => array('"TblB2"."id"'),
        'table' => $db->fullTableName($this->TblB),
        'alias' => 'TblB2',
        'limit' => 1,
        'offset' => null,
        'joins' => array(),
        'conditions' => array('"TblB"."tbl_a_id" = "TblB2"."tbl_a_id"'),
        'order' => '"TblB2"."id" DESC',
        'group' => null

    )
);
$subQueryExpression = $db->expression($subQuery);

$conditions[] = $subQueryExpression;
$data = $this->TblB->find('all', compact('conditions'));
```

See the docs for more on [retrieving data using a sub-query](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries).

Comment: I don't think your sql is correct. If your subquery only returns 1 row, then only 1 id will be chosen. The sample data shows that 3 different id's are needed in the solution.

Comment: @AgRizzo I've test this query against the sample data shown in the question and it gave the desired result. I've seen this method used elsewhere, although can't remember the source.

Comment: @AgRizzo http://stackoverflow.com/a/924501/311992 (I believe this is a similar situation just not in CakePHP).

Comment: I started a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6f30/1) with your code. At a minimum, your SQL has a couple syntax errors.

Comment: @AgRizzo sorry, there was a typo in my original query. I've fixed that. As the question relates to CakePHP there should really be a primary key on `tbl_b` which is what I've based my answer on; if not then my answer should at least provide some guidance to solving the question being asked. See the updated SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ca3e/1/0

Comment: Sorry, I misread your query, thinking the subquery was a JOIN table, not in the WHERE. FYI - The subquery in the WHERE clause may not perform as well as a subquery as a JOIN table. I built another [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fc4a/1) with many more rows and to show another solution.