# show last comment which just 1 comment per user

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a normal comments table:

`| id | comment | date | user | post | status |`

I want to fetch my 10 last comments with just 1 comment per user, I mean something like this:

I have this data:

`| id | comment | date      | user | post | 
| 1  | text1   | 2016-04-01| 1    | 1    |
| 2  | text2   | 2016-04-02| 2    | 1    |
| 3  | text3   | 2016-04-03| 1    | 2    |
| 4  | text4   | 2016-04-04| 4    | 3    |
| 5  | text5   | 2016-04-04| 3    | 5    |
| 6  | text6   | 2016-04-05| 2    | 4    |
| 7  | text7   | 2016-04-07| 5    | 3    |
| 8  | text8   | 2016-04-10| 4    | 9    |
| 9  | text9   | 2016-04-11| 3    | 7    |
| 10 | text10  | 2016-04-12| 5    | 8    |`

and I want get this :

`| 10 | text10  | 2016-04-12| 5    | 8    |
| 9  | text9   | 2016-04-11| 3    | 7    |
| 8  | text8   | 2016-04-10| 4    | 9    |
| 6  | text6   | 2016-04-05| 2    | 4    |
| 3  | text3   | 2016-04-03| 1    | 2    |`

I use this sql statement:

```
SELECT  *
FROM  `comments`
GROUP BY  `user` 
ORDER BY MAX(`id`) DESC
```

This fetches comments with correct order for user but wrong order for comment's date:

`| 7  | text7   | 2016-04-07| 5    | 3    |
| 9  | text9   | 2016-04-11| 3    | 7    |
| 4  | text4   | 2016-04-04| 4    | 3    |
| 6  | text6   | 2016-04-05| 2    | 4    |
| 1  | text1   | 2016-04-01| 1    | 1    |`

Comment: you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924494/mysql-group-by-ordering?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

#### Why it doesn't work with `GROUP BY`

`SELECT *` cannot be used with `GROUP BY`; it is invalid SQL. `GROUP BY` doesn't select table rows. It creates groups of rows using the provided expressions then, from each group, it generates a new record and computes each column of this new record using the values involved in the expression.

The columns that appear in the `SELECT` clause must satisfy one of the following rules:

- also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- are used with [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html);
- are functionally-dependent on the columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

While `*` is a shortcut for all the column names of the table(s) used by the query, for your query only the `user` column satisfy one of the requirements above.

[Before version 5.7.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) MySQL didn't implement the third rule above. It used to accept queries that contain in the `SELECT` clause columns that do not follow any of the `GROUP BY` requirements. The value returned by the query for such columns was [indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Since version 5.7.5, MySQL rejects the `GROUP BY` queries that do satisfy the requirements.

#### The solution

Either way, the solution for your problem doesn't involve `GROUP BY`. It can be easily accomplished using a `LEFT JOIN` with the correct conditions:

```
SELECT lc.*
FROM comments lc               # 'lc' from 'last comment'
    LEFT JOIN comments nc      # 'nc' from 'newer comment'
        ON lc.user = nc.user   # both comments belong to the same user
        AND lc.id < nc.id      # 'nc' is newer than 'lc'
WHERE nc.id IS NULL            # there is no 'newer comment'
ORDER BY lc.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

#### How it works

It joins the table `comments`, aliased as `lc` ("lc" from the "last comment" of a user) against itself, aliased as `nc` ("nc" from "newer comment"). The join clause matches each entry of `lc` with all entries of `nc` that belong to the same user (`lc.user = nc.user`) and are newer (`lc.id < nc.id`; I assumed the IDs are assigned sequentially and newer comments have larger values for `id`).

The use of `LEFT JOIN` ensures that every row of `lc` appears in the result of the join, even when no matching row is found in `nc` (because there is no newer comment of the same user). In this case, `NULL` is used instead of the fields of `nc`. The `WHERE` clause keeps in the final result set only the rows that have `NULL` in `nc.id`; this means in the `lc` part they contain the most recent comment of each user.

The `SELECT` clause contains all the fields of `lc` (those of `nc` are all `NULL`, anyway). The `ORDER BY` clause can be used to sort the result set. `ORDER BY lc.id DESC` puts the most recent comments first and the `LIMIT` clause keeps the result set to a decent size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (
    SELECT id,comment,MAX(date) as date,`user`,post,status
    FROM comments 
    GROUP BY `user`) AS t
JOIN comments AS u USING (id)
```