# laravel - Get last comments with unique user

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how I can get fetch my 10 last comments with just 1 comment per user in laravel

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578370/show-last-comment-which-just-1-comment-per-user) but I want do it with eloquent in clean way

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  if you designed your tables wrong it is most likely that you will need to loop outside of Eloquent.

Comment: provide more information. So that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
Comment::groupBy('user_id')->limit(10)->get();
```

If you want to get latest comments, create a class called UserComment and  store latest comment_id for each user and update it for each new comment created, then You can fetch latest 10 comments by

```
UserComment::orderBy('updated_at')->limit(10)->get();
```

Comment: groupBy isn't solution because not return latest comments

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic:

`Comment::groupBy('user_id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();`

Comment: `skip(0)->take(10);` is missing

Comment: groupBy isn't solution because not return latest comments

Comment: `orderBy('id', 'desc')` OR `orderBy('id', 'created_at')` will take latest records, now its **how to fetch 10 comments 1 per each?**.
You sure not to do a PHP iteration with the collection?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find the latest comments by the highest ids:

```
$ids = Comment::selectRaw('MAX(id) id')->groupBy('user_id')->take(10)->pluck('id');
$comments = Comment::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderByDesc('id')->get();
```

Comment: same as others, groupBy isn't solution because not return latest comments

Comment: That's achieved by `MAX(id)`. Did you try it?