# MySQL ORDER BY then GROUP By

Tags: mysql

I have the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC) t GROUP BY pcid

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC) t GROUP BY pcid
```

I am unable to get the GROUP BY to be in the correct order.  It always pulls from the lowest value.

Am I missing some syntax that is oblivious to me?

After looking for the past several hours to find a solution to this issue, I have been unable to resolve.  This question has been asked because I have been unable to find the answer.

Here is my table structure:

table
  id,primary
  pcid
  cpu
  memphy
  memcom
  memvir
  timestamp

I have tried sorting by timestamp and id with no luck.

Comment: why are you using a nested query to do order by and group by? Can you show us table structure and sample data?

Comment: Are you trying to get the row with the highest value for each value of `column`? Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/924501/114900

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Group By ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924494/mysql-group-by-ordering)

Comment: So why would I use a join when all the information is in one table

Answer (score 0):

You should give more detail but it might be something like this :

```
 SELECT column, highest, count(somecolumnname)
 FROM table_name 
 GROUP BY column, highest 
 ORDER BY highest DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should return the rows that you need:

```
select
  t.*
from
  table t INNER JOIN (select column, max(highest) m_highest
                      from table
                      grouo by column) tm
  on t.column=tm.column and t.highest=tm.m_highest
```

The subquery will return the maximum highest per column, then you join back to the original table t and return all rows that have highest=the maximum highest per column.